# Firebase Analytics events, is there a default app install event?

Tags: android, firebase, google-analytics, google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

i'm trying to calculate the period between installing the application from the store and first open. Is there any default event in firebase (can't find one here [Firebase Events](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/9234069?hl=fr)) or any workaround to detect when user user install first time the app?

Comment: also looking for this question, apparently there are default events that are not listed on the Firebase Events link, like app_install

Comment: where can I find those events? @ralphgabb